# Youtube-dl OUTPUT TEMPLATE %(title)s.%(ext)s is not working with set /p in windows

Tags: youtube, windows-10, filenames, youtube-dl

I used the batch file with commands :-
**set /p ytlink="Enter the link of Youtube Video:-  "

youtube-dl -f "bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]" -o "D:\Videos\%(title)s.%(ext)s" %ytlink%

pause**
but the output file name is **(ext)s.webm** ,it seems cmd is treating **%(title)s.%** in **-o "D:\Videos\%(title)s.%(ext)s"** as variable.So how to get video title?
OS=Windows 10 64bit 1909
youtube-dl=2020.01.24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use double % in a batch file.

```
   set /p ytlink="Enter the link of Youtube Video:- "
youtube-dl -f "bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]" -o "D:\Videos\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s"     %ytlink%
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will need it. Based on 1957classic answer. Download video and audio in the best quality to your desktop with the original name with the url taken from the clipboard.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%I in (powershell.exe) do if "%%~$PATH:I" neq "" (
    set getclip=powershell "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;$tb=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox;$tb.Multiline=$true;$tb.Paste();$tb.Text"
)
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%getclip% ^| findstr /n "^"') do (
    set "line=%%I" & set "line=!line:*:=!"
)
set "psCommand="[Environment]::GetFolderPath('DesktopDirectory')""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "Desktop=%%I"
%~d0"%~p0"youtube-dl.exe -f "bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]" -o "!Desktop!\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" !line!
```